# XCode Code Folding Line like Android Studio

Tags: xcode

When I create a function, I would like to see a line immediately indicating it when I look at the function from a distance, within the curly brackets. Below, you will see a screen shot from Android Studio as an example. I want to see the same in XCode.

[image: This is image]

I can't find a line setting like this on XCode

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Text Editing -> Code folding rebbon

[image: Demo]

##### Demo

[image: Demo]

Also, holding command and moving the pointer on top of a scop will highlight it

---

You can also enable `invisibles` from the `editor options` if you like:

[image: Invisibles]